# Arbitrary element in a tensor product is a finite sum.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Many books on algebra say that any arbitrary element in a tensor product is a finite sum of pure tensors, however, I cannot clearly see why this is true. Actually, if both of the spaces $U$ and $V$ are finidimensional, then $U \otimes V$ is finidimensional as well. Then it is really true: any element $x \in U \otimes V$ can be expressed as a finite linear combination of basis elements, and so it can be expressed as a finite sum of pure tensors:
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} c_{ij} (u_i \otimes v_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} ((c_{ij} u_i) \otimes v_j).
$$

But why is it true when $U$ and $V$ are not finidimensional? I clearly do not understand this, please give me a hint.

Comment: Probably your confusion arises from infinite sums? But they are not allowed anyway (even for arbitrary vector spaces). They don't belong to the language of vector spaces. You cannot write them down.

Comment: But if some vector space is has infinite dimension, then it has infinitely many basis elements, and their sum is an element of this space as well? Sorry, I am getting confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your doubt can be expressed just the same as "Why in an infinite dimensional vector space any element in it is a **finite** linear combination of a (finite, of course) subset of a basis of the space?" .

This is so just definition *based* on the axioms of vector space (or module, or algebra or whatever): we know how to do finite sums, we do not how to do infinite sums *unless* some further structure kicks in, say a normed space.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, now I understand this.

Comment: By definition questions like this are not stupid.

Comment: Your question was not stupid at all: tensor products are tough to swallow first time they're met.

Comment: I don't understand this, can someone explain to me why any element can be expressed as a finite linear combination of a subset of a basis of the space from the axioms of the space (which in particular)?

Comment: @MartinGeller That's what the definition of "linear combinartion", or more accurately: FINITE linear combination, means in an infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

If $U,V$ are vector spaces over some field $K$, then $U \otimes_K V$ is defined to be the universal vector space equipped with a bilinear map $U \times V \to U \otimes_K V$. The subspace generated by the image of this map still satisfies the universal property. Hence, this subspace must be the whole of $U \otimes_K V$. Alternatively, use the explicit construction of $U \otimes_K V$.

It is misguided to work with bases here. In particular, no dimension has to be considered. And the same statements hold for arbitrary modules.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific please? Why does the universal property shows that the sum is finite?

Comment: In vector spaces, sums are finite by definition.